# Bug when forming the file path

Tags: python, python-3.x

The start () function runs continuously, until forced to stop.

```
import time
import datetime
import math
import image_processing

images_folder = "images/"
folder_name = images_folder + str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
screen_data = image_processing.getScreenData()
stack_collection = image_processing.getStackImages()

def start():
    for item in screen_data:
        image_name = str(math.floor(time.time()))
        image_path = folder_name + "/" + str(item['screen_area']) + "/" + image_name + ".png"
        image_processing.imaging(item['x_coordinate'], item['y_coordinate'], item['width'], item['height'],
                                         image_path, item['screen_area'])
```

The problem is - sometimes(not often) some images saves in `/images` folder, not in full path. Why can this happen?

Comment: If you run from root directory instead of whatever folder you wanted to run it from.

Comment: Please be more precise and in the code there is no point where you actually run the "start" function.
When building paths, you should not just add strings. I recommend taking a look at the pathlib library: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Generally, it is saver to use `os.path.join()` to create file paths. If you don't specify an absolute path, the path will be relative to the path where your script is located.

Comment: what do you mean by "some images saves in `/images` folder, not in full path"? What kind of path do they take?

Comment: @DocDriven almost always path looks like images/2018-07-13/1/1531503426.png. but seldom some image saves in just /images

Answer (score 0):

To build a directory path you can always use the `os` library:

```
import os

os.path.join(folder_name , str(item['screen_area']) , image_name + ".png")
```

[Python os library reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

Comment: I build path like you show. But some images still saving in /images folder.

Comment: Try printing your image_path to troubleshoot it. Maybe there are some item['screen_area'] missing attributes?

Comment: There is ok with item['screen_area']. The incorrect path not many(2-3% of all images)

Answer (score 0):

You're building a relative path, and relative path are resolved against the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory),  not against the directory where the script lives. If you want to force your files to be stored in a given directory, you must use an absolute path.

Also, don't build path by string concatenation, use the `os.path` module instead.